# How To Carve a Design

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model this sword, and I'm having trouble making the base of the sword (the grip). How would I go about doing this?
[image: Example]

Comment: What will you use it for? Rendering, 3d printing, game asset?

Comment: I don't really think this is a case for sculpting, as this is hard surface modeling when you want to model forms of the mesh, smoothen them with Subsurf and refine the mesh to keep sharp edges where needed. There are quite a few of techniques for that all falling under term "hard surface modeling". This question is a bit too broad though for this site as of now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest modelling the basic shape and then sculpting, then you can retopo a low poly and bake the detail from the sculpted piece to the low poly, if you are planning on it being a game ready asset.

If you aren't, just stopping after the sculpting phase is OK.

Comment: is there a video you could link me cause i barely know sculpting

Comment: take a look at these, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVpwivEl_6o 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZnUgt659oI Sculpting is very different from traditional modelling, so it might take some time to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also paint a bump map manually if you are already going to be using image textures in your material.

Answer (score -2):

sculpting and retopo is the best approach